# Map not changing after filter

Tags: python, filter, qgsvectorlayer, qgsexpression

I use qgis 3.4.4 and I make a filter on vector layer. Here is my code:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
for layer_id, layer in layers.items():
    if (layer.name() == "csv_points_acc") or (layer.name() == "csv_points_amb"):
        print(layer.name())
        expression = """"dateposte" like '%2019-01%'"""
        request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)
        matches = 0
        for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
           matches += 1
        print(matches)
```

The matches printed correspond to the data but there is no change in the map. Can anyone help me to make the filter work to the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the following

```py
layer.setSubsetString(expression)
```